# swi-prolog print multiple variables

Tags: prolog

I want to print multiple variables in swi-prolog, currently I am writing in this way:

```
writeln('child link : '),
writeln(LINK_CHILD),
writeln('rule - four'),
writeln(REND_PARENTI),
writeln(REND_CHILDI)
```

so every variable gets printed on new line, I could not figure out way to print them in single line. I appreciate any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either use `write` instead of `writeln`, or even better, use [`format`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=format-predicates):

```
?- format("~a~n~a:~a~n", [x, y, z]).
x
y:z
true.
```

Or, for your case, something like:

```
format("child link: ~w rule - four ~w", [LINK_CHILD, REND_PARENT....]),
flush_output
```

You need the `flush_output` if you want to print out before you get to the end of the line. See SWI-Prolog's [primitive character IO](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=chario).

Answer (score 1):

Writing on a single line would be done with `write/1` i.o. `writeln/1`.

Writing an arbitrary number of atoms can be done by calling a predicate (`write/1` in this case) for a list of arguments (the list of printed atoms in this case) by using `maplist/3`.

The resultant code is:

```
?- maplist(write, ['child link : ',LINK_CHILD,'rule - four',REND_PARENTI,REND_CHILDI]).
```

Comment: It is better to use `forall` when you are evaluating a predicate for its side effect: it just conveys your intent better than `maplist` in this particular case. But I guess it's a matter of taste after all.

Comment: @Wouter: thanks, but when I added `maplist(write, ['Link : ',LINK, ' REND ', REND])` in my file.pro which I am calling from python script, it does not show any message written on screem

Comment: @nlper The standard output stream is buffered. It is flushed on a newline: `format("~n")` or `nl`, or you can flush it manually using `flush_output`.