# The results my Prolog program outputs are not what what they are supposed to be

Tags: prolog

I am making a prolog program in which a person can find the marks of students. They can do this by entering this code `marks_chemistry(personsname)`.

However when this code is entered the output is `no` instead of what their marks are supposed to be.

I am fairly new to prolog and coding in general so any help would be greatly appreciated.

`male(albert).
 male(paul).
 female(jessica).
 female(rebecca).
 female(natalie).`

```
marks_chemistry(paul) :-
   marksA is 85,
   write('Paul got', marksA, '85/100').
```

Comment: I think you need to provide more details about your code @Hannan

Comment: That is all my code

Comment: All your code or all code in the application? I think it is useful to know under what condition is your code tested, otherwise it is hard to say why it isn't working. Anyways I am no prolog expert just triaging the question. So if you could provide more information on how the tests are being setup and how you get to "no" ouptut it will help people answer your qeustion.

Comment: oh okay thanks for the help.

Comment: There's no need to use `is/2` to assign a value as in `MarksA is 85`. The purpose of `is/2` is to evaluate an arithmetic expression, so if there is no expression on the right, regular equality will work: `MarksA = 85`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some notes on your current approach:

- Predicates always output yes/no (or they go into an infinite loop). They cannot "return" other values. However, during their evaluation, they can have side effects like printing messages to the console.
- Prolog is case-sensitive, lower-case identifiers are understood as predicates/function symbols, upper-case identifiers as variables. Therefore, asking Prolog `?- a = b.` will give you the answer `no`, but `?- X = b.` will give you the answer `X = b`, asking `?- a(X) = b.` will give you `no` but `?- a(X) = b(c).` will give you `X = c`.

  When you write `marksA is 85`, Prolog will check if the term `markA` is equal to the arithmetic evaluation of `85`, which is always false. Instead, you should use `MarksA is 85`. Here, `MarkA` is understood as a variable, and because the variable hasn't been assigned yet, Prolog will assign it with `85`.
- The `write` predicate doesn't support variadic arguments. You either have to use `write` for each argument individually, or use formatting (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29230608/swi-prolog-print-multiple-variables)).

Based on these observations, your program could be rewritten to:

```
marks_chemistry(paul) :-
   MarksA is 85,
   write('Paul got '),
   write(MarksA),
   writeln('/100').
```

Querying the program gives:

```
?- marks_chemistry(paul).
Paul got 85/100
true.
```