# How to print a list of pairs?

Tags: prolog

Nobody cares to answer my very important long question so I keep it short.

```
% https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29230608/swi-prolog-print-multiple-variables
pretty_row(Ls) :- maplist(format, Ls).

uci(w-k, 'K').
uci(b-q, 'q').

ls([w-k, b-q]).
```

`?- ls(L), pretty_row(L).`

```
% Expected output 
Kq
```

Answer (score 0):

```
% Prolog

pretty_row(Ls) :- maplist(format, Ls).

uci(w-k, 'K').
uci(b-q, 'q').

ls([w-k, b-q]).

ucis([], []).
ucis([P|Rest], [Z|ZRest]) :- uci(P, Z), ucis(Rest, ZRest).
```

I am not sure if there is a built in predicate that does what `ucis` do.

Comment: How about defining the display predicate as `pretty_row(Ls) :- maplist(uci, Ls, Names), maplist(format, Names).`

Comment: Ok thanks, I eventually learned that trick to give two lists to `maplist` to unify with `uci/2`.